# reindex command error (No alive nodes found in your cluster)

Tags: magento2, reindex

hi whenever i run reindex command in my console it keeps giving me following error : pleaae give me suggestion how can i resolve it ,

> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException: No alive
>   nodes found in your cluster in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\ConnectionPool\StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:51

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: yep i had another searching extension which was colliding with default search so i disabled them , delete all static files along with cache re deploy than it worked.

Comment: For me, it was setting Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search to MySQL. It was set to  Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Magento and getting 'No alive nodes found in your cluster' error while reindexing.

**Make sure you have updated following  :**

1. Your Host and port : `'[host]:[port]'`. Eg: **'es-node1.fqdn:9200, es-node2.fqdn:9200' or 'localhost:9200'** in `Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search`.
2. Update your indices alias name and indices name pattern in admin configuration same as above.

Try this, and clear cache and reindex. It will solve your issue.

[image]

Comment: I don't find this path : System -> Configuration -> Elastic Configuration. Please tell me in detail.

Comment: Muhammad Ahmed its in Sys -> configuration -> cataogue -> catalogue search

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using Magento and getting 'No alive nodes found in your cluster' error while reindexing**

Please make sure you have install Elastic Search into your system.

if you are using ubantu then please run following command

**sudo apt-get install elasticsearch**

Then Goto Admin -> Store -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog

then configure as follow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your elasticsearch is installed and running by simply executing this command

curl localhost:9200 If not installed then: sudo apt update

Then run the installation: sudo apt install elasticsearch

First, reload the systemd configuration: sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Then, enable the Elasticsearch service with: sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

And finally, after the service is enabled, start Elasticsearch: sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service

If you make changes to configuration files, or need to restart Elasticsearch for any reason, use: sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service

Then made configuration in admin, that may looks like this, enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be caused by configuration as @Khan-arman explained or by elasticsearch service. I discovered both issues below:

#### Check the configuration

First let's check if your configuration is correct:

1. Update your host and port: '[host]:[port]'. E.g.: 'localhost:9200' in `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search` or if you are you are using Elastic Suite in `Stores > Configuration > ElasticSuit > Basic configuration`.
2. Update your indices alias name and indices name pattern in admin configuration same as above.

   [image]
3. Clear cache by going to `System > Cache Management` or using this command (on your server in Magento installation folder):

   ```
   bin/magento cache:clean
   ```
4. Reindex by visiting `System > Index Management` or running command below:

   ```
   # Update catalog search
   bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext 

   # Or reindex all indexers
   bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```

#### Check Elasticsearch

If the error still stands, it might be the issue with the elasticsearch service on your server. To solve this follow the steps below:

1. Log into your server
2. Check if the elasticsearch is running:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
   ```
3. Try to start it if it's not running, or restart it if it's running:

   ```
   # Start elasticsearch
   sudo systemctl start elasticsearch

   # Or restart elasticsearch
   sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
   ```

   You've found the issue if you encounter an error here and your elasticsearch doesn't start. Solve the issue first. If you don't get any errors and elasticsearch starts, continue.
4. Navigate to your Magento installation folder
5. Reindex all indexers

   ```
   bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```
6. Clear the cache

   ```
   bin/magento cache:flush
   ```

Your problem should have been solved now.

Answer (score 0):

How To Fix "Indexer Reindex Required" Error In Magento 2.4.4

For Local Server

1st Start -------> elasticsearch
2nd Start--------> Xampp or Laragon

then Go to Magento root Directory
Run CMD Command

Paste and Enter Following Command

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

--------After Finish------

Then Paste and Enter Following Command

php bin/magento cache:flush

its woking...

Answer (score -1):

I have found the perfect solution for this issue.

Edit config/elasticsearch.yml
Please, change the network.host: 0.0.0.0
After changing the config pls restart the apps
Don't forget to uncomment network host

Enjoy!