# Creating products not possible

Tags: magento2

When I try to create a product this shows:
[image]

I dont know what is wrong. I tried to change the specifications for the prodct. Does any one have an idea.

Thanks for every help!

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647851/the-stock-item-was-unable-to-be-saved-please-try-again-magento-2-4-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647851/the-stock-item-was-unable-to-be-saved-please-try-again-magento-2-4-0) visit this site fully explained and answered your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing issues with product creation and saving in Magento 2, there could be several potential causes. Here are some troubleshooting steps you can follow:

- Check error logs: Review the Magento logs for any error messages related to the product creation process. You can find the logs in the {magento_root}/var/log/ directory.
- Verify database connectivity: Ensure that your Magento installation is properly connected to the database. Check your database configuration settings in the app/etc/env.php file and verify that the database server is accessible.
- Check for conflicting extensions: Disable any recently installed extensions or custom modules to identify if they are causing any conflicts. Try creating a product without any additional extensions enabled to see if the issue persists.
- Clear cache: Clear the Magento cache by running the following command from the Magento root directory:

> ```
> bin/magento cache:clean
> ```

- Check file permissions: Verify that the appropriate file permissions are set for the Magento installation. Files should typically be owned by the web server user and have the correct read/write permissions.
- Reindex data: Reindex the necessary data by running the following command from the Magento root directory:

> ```
> bin/magento indexer:reindex
> ```

- Check for customizations: If you have made any customizations related to product creation, review your custom code for any potential issues. Ensure that your customizations are implemented correctly and do not conflict with the standard Magento functionality.
- Debugging: Enable Magento's developer mode and enable error reporting to get more detailed error messages. You can enable developer mode by running the following command:

> ```
> bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
> ```

- Additionally, check the browser console for any JavaScript errors that may be affecting the product saving process.

Comment: When I run "bin/magento indexer:reindex" all indexes are rebuilt successfully except the last one, where it says "Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster". Do you have an explaination for this, please?

Comment: This issue is related your Elasticsearch instead of Mysql. please check once that elasticsearch is working or not. this commands might be helpful for check elastic search status : 1. sudo service elasticsearch status  (for checking the Running Status)
2. sudo service elasticsearch start  ( for Start )
3. sudo service elasticsearch restart    ( for Restart )

Comment: please check this for error: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208822/reindex-command-error-no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster

Comment: Thank you, I will try that one. But another problem has appeared. I found a different suggestion by using "sudo chown -R user:user /var/www/html/" but after running it the whole website is blank. Is there a way to redo it?

Comment: when you ran the command sudo chown -R user:user /var/www/html/ to change the ownership of files and directories in your Magento installation. However, this resulted in a blank website, indicating that the ownership and permissions were set incorrectly. =>Follow these steps: 1.Identify the original ownership by referring to the default ownership used in a Magento installation, which is typically www-data:www-data assuming the web server user is www-data.

Comment: 2.Reset the ownership and permissions by executing the following commands:
=> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
=> sudo find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
=> sudo find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
This will set the ownership to www-data:www-data, and give appropriate read and execute permissions (755) to directories, and read permissions (644) to files.
3.Clear cache: php bin/magento cache:flush After completing these steps, the ownership and permissions should be restored to their original state, and your website should be accessible again.

Comment: Thank you so much, Charmi!! You helped mie alot. I could solve the problem.

Comment: You're welcome @Mah97! I'm glad I could help you solve the problem. If you have any more questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask.!!